# PHP persistent delayed HTTP connection

Tags: php, http

I'm writing an app the contacts a PHP script on a server to receive messages. It does this once every few seconds, and the server replies with any new messages (or no messages if there aren't any new messages). The messages are generated by another PHP script and put into a database for the message checker script to check and remove once the app receives the message and acknowledges that it has processed the message.

Is there a way for the app to send just one request, and have the reply sent only when there are new messages (maybe an hour after the app first sent the request), so that the app doesn't waste internet data, and also doesn't have to wait up to a few seconds (or however long I set the request interval to) before receiving the message, and maybe have the reply sent directly from the other script that generates the messages, which would mean that I wouldn't need a database anymore, and maybe even keep the connection open for further messages to be sent without the app having to make another request.

Comment: There's a way for everything, but the problem is that you didn't specify *what* your app is. Is it a web page, is it a mobile app, what tech is used? You just described web sockets. Instead of asking *"hey, are there messages?"* you simply get a push message that hands you the new messages. Also, your concern about connection and performance - worry about that when you start getting traffic. Premature optimization is the root of all evil. In  your case, you've a working app and you're optimizing something that's not even apparent yet.

Comment: @N.B. My app is an Android app that sends HTTP requests to the php script running on the server.

Comment: The easiest approach ( without the complexity of websockets ) would be to use `Server Sent Events` - aka Window EventSource. The connection is initiated by the client - the request is sent to the PHP script which loops infinitely. How that script is written determines what happens in the client but it can easily be set to send a message when new data is available

Comment: @RamRaider Would it work between scripts? Like instead of infinitely looping, it just quits without replying, and another script somehow sends a reply later on.

Answer (score 0):

Simple Answer: yes, this technique is called websockets, you have a stable connection over which you can also push instead of just poll (like ajax)

Comment: I think I've heard of WebSockets. Would it work between scripts? Like where would I store the connection details so that I could send a reply from another script (isn't PHP mostly instances of scripts that run independently from each other)?

Comment: just research websockets, you can make realtime bi-directional application you need to run a websocket server because communication is on ws(s) protocoll, the client connects with js, so it is its own process on server check integration for example "ratchet websocket" http://socketo.me/